# CMake warns of conflict with library in implicit directories

Tags: linux, cmake

I have a cross-toolchain created with "buildroot 2013.02" and "Sourcery CodeBench ARM 2012.09". In this toolchain I have the library libX11.so twice:

- at /opt/...linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib is the ARM object to link with target files
- at /opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/lib is the x86-64 object to link with the host files

For some reason, cmake confuses the paths and I get this warning:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:194 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target vibkart because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libX11.so.6] in /opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

I'm using the following toolchainfile.cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -pipe -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -O2 " CACHE STRING "Buildroot CFLAGS" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -pipe -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -O2 " CACHE STRING "Buildroot CXXFLAGS" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE 0)
set(CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH "/opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/bin")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} "/opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot")
set(OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR "/opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/include/")
set(OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY "/opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so")
```

Questions:

1. Where are these paths defined?
2. How can I exclude the x86 library path from cross compilation?

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Brad King](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-November/033295.html) I realized that the path is added whenever I'm linking to a library of this directory.

Due to a wrong entry in the toolchainfile.cmake the x86-64 path was added. So changing the following lines resolved the problem:

```
-set(OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR "/opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/include/")
+set(OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR "/opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/")
-set(OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY "/opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so")
+set(OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY "/opt/vibkart/toolchain-arm/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so")
```